# Как присвоить переменной случайное значение?

Tags: c#

Как присвоить переменной случайное значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя класс [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random.aspx): [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx), [NextDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx). Например:

```
Random random = new Random();
int r = random.Next(0, 100);
```

присваивает r случайное значение в диапазоне от 0 до 100.

Comment: От 0 до 99 (верхняя граница - исключительно).

Answer (score 1):

Для лучшей имитации случайности достаточно сделать Random статическим:

```
static Random random = new Random();
int r = random.Next(0, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rn = new Random(DataTime.Now.Milisecond);
int a = rn.Next(1, 100);
```

Для лучшей имитации случайности советую юзать DataTime.